# how can I sum the pricees in list view and show it with toast?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to show the price and numbers in a list with toast. the app runs and works, but when I'm tap the submit button to check out the prices it closes.

before these codes below, everything works. so I know the problem is here but don't understand where...

```
 public void onclick(View view){
             SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

        int num=0;
        int sum=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount() ; i++) {
                if (checked.get(i)) {
                num++;
                switch (i){
                    case 0:
                        sum+=60;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        sum+=46;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        sum+=36;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        sum+=34;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        sum+=19;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        sum+=5;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        sum+=3;
                        break;
                }
                String s="";
                s="you selected: "+ Integer.toString(num)+ "items";
                s+="\n\r";
                s+="price is: "+ Integer.toString(sum)+ "toman";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is these in MainActivity? if In MainActivity use only `this` instead of `MainActivity.this`.

Comment: show the Logcat and error line.

Answer (score 0):

sum all price in onBindviewHolder and toast it when you have last time created

```
sum += price;
if(isLastItem){
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,sum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

Comment: and please add logs for more clarification on this